# Correct formulation of a set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $A = \{k : k\in\Bbb Z^+, 1\le k\le p\}$. 
Let $B$ be a subset of $A$.

I want to create a set called $C$ that contains every $(k,k+2)$ number pair of which both components are in $B$.

For example if $p=7$, then $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. Let $B = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then $C=\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)\}$.

Is 
$B = \{a1, a2, ... a(n-1), a(n): a(n)\in A\}$ 
$C = \{(a1,a2),(a2,a3), ... (a(n-1),a(n))$}

mathematically correct, or if not, how should I formulate it?

Comment: Did you intend $C$ to contain every pair $(k, k+1)$ or as written, pairs of the form $(k,k+2)$?  Additionally, what is the relevance of the comment that $B$ should be in the same order as $A$?  It is not clear where you are trying to reach.

Comment: Ahh sorry a typing mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. My bad...

Comment: I'd just write $C = \{(k,k+2)| k, k+2 \in B\}$.  That's all.  If you write out $B=\{a_1,a_2,....\}$ you have not reason to assume $a_2 = a_1 + 2$.  Note: if $B=\{1,3,4,7\}$ then $C = \emptyset$. So there's no point in thinking we can list the elements of $C$ systematically.

Answer (score 1):

The most rigorous and explicit way to declare your desired set is -- if I understand correctly -- as follows:
$$C=\{u|\ (\exists k)(u=(k, k+2) \wedge k, k+2 \in B)\}$$

The relation in $u$ which defines $C$ is indeed "collectivising" (i.e. there does exist a set containing precisely those objects $u$ that satisfy it) since it entails that $u \in B \times (B+2)$.

---

**P.S.** Since I am led to believe that the above formulation is not the exact one you are looking for, let me also present the version:

$$D\colon=\{u |\ (\exists k)(u=(k, k+1) \wedge k, k+1 \in B)\},$$
also "collectivising" since any $u$ satisfying the defining relation is an element of $B \times (B+1)$.

Many other variations on the same theme are possible, such as for instance defining the set of all pairs of natural numbers of the form $(k, k+2)$ such that $k \in A$ and $k+1 \in B$:

$$E=\{u |\ (\exists k)(u=(k, k+2) \wedge k \in A \wedge k+1 \in B)\},$$
again "collectivising" since the condition on $u$ entails $u \in A \times (B+1)$.

Comment: I am sorry I made a type error in the question. Could you, please, rewrite your answer according to it? My bad. Thanks!

Comment: @BélaTilinger You have nothing to apologise for. I did take a look at your edited question and to be honest didn't spot any change from the original. At any rate, I will expand my answer with some alternative versions that might refer exactly to what you seek to achieve.